Next.js website update without work files
I uploaded minified Next.js files to the server, but now my work files are missing from my hand. I tried updating the phone number in the uploaded files, but the changes aren't reflecting on the website. Is there any way to update the phone number without the source files in next.js website
I need to update my website with some small changes using the minified files in the server. How can I do that with out source files. Please help

If you have a next.js static build, search for the string you want to change in the whole folder, for example:
grep +1234567890555 *

it may find more than one occurence. Just update them all and it should work. Make sure you clear your browser's cache before reloading.
